# GridBagLayout is not displaying as expected

Tags: java, swing, layout, gridbaglayout

This is my first foray into GridBagLayout, have reviewed the Java documentation online (as well as a lot of SO Q&As) and I've creating a panel that I'm expecting to display as such:

```
+--------------------------+
|      choose a timer      |
+--------+--------+--------+
|  5min  |  25min | 30min  |
+--------+--------+--------+
|         00:00:00         |
+--------+--------+--------+
|  Start |  Pause |  Quit  |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

and here's the GridBagLayout I'm using.

```
public class ButtonSel extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JLabel buttonSelLabel = new JLabel("Choose Which Timer To Run");
    JButton pomoButton    = new JButton("00:25:00");
    JButton shrtButton    = new JButton("00:05:00");
    JButton longButton    = new JButton("00:30:00");
    JButton startButton   = new JButton("Go");
    JButton pauseButton   = new JButton("Pause");
    JButton quitButton    = new JButton("Quit");
    JLabel textDisplay    = new JLabel("00:00:00");
     //
    JPanel timerPanel     = new JPanel();
     //

public ButtonSel() {
    super("ButtonTest");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

            add(buttonSelLabel, c);    // line 1
             c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
             c.gridx = 1;
             c.gridy = 1;
             c.gridwidth = 3;

            add(pomoButton, c);        // line 2
             c.gridx = 1;
             c.gridy = 2;
             c.gridwidth = 1;

            add(shrtButton, c);
             c.gridx = 2;
             c.gridy = 2;
             c.gridwidth = 1;

            add(longButton, c);
             c.gridx = 3;
             c.gridy = 2;
             c.gridwidth = 1;

            add(textDisplay, c);       // line 3
             c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
             c.gridx=1;
             c.gridy=3;
             c.gridwidth=3;

            add(startButton, c);       // line 4
             c.gridx = 1;
             c.gridy = 4;
             c.gridwidth = 1;

            add(pauseButton, c);
             c.gridx = 2;
             c.gridy = 4;
             c.gridwidth = 1;

            add(quitButton, c);
             c.gridx = 2;
             c.gridy = 4;
             c.gridwidth = 1;

    pomoButton.addActionListener(this);
    shrtButton.addActionListener(this);
    longButton.addActionListener(this);
    startButton.addActionListener(this);
    pauseButton.addActionListener(this);
    quitButton.addActionListener(this);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent radioSelect) {
    Object source = radioSelect.getSource();
    if (source == pomoButton)
        textDisplay.setText("00:25:00");
    else
    if (source == shrtButton)
        textDisplay.setText("00:05:00");
    else
    if (source == longButton)
        textDisplay.setText("00:30:00");
    else
    if (source == startButton)
        textDisplay.setText("Started");
    else
    if (source == pauseButton)
        textDisplay.setText("Paused");
    else
    if (source == quitButton)
        textDisplay.setText("Quit");
    else
        textDisplay.setText("00:00:00");
}
}
```

I was getting this output,

[image]

and taking a cue about horizontal alignment from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163501/laying-out-components-in-gridbaglayout-not-as-expected) I added the `HORIZONTAL` constraints to the the fields. Now I'm getting:

[image]

I've used `(0,0)` and `(1,1)` as my starting `(x,y)` coordinates, interestingly enough, with the same results.

Can anyone see something that I'm missing?

Comment: Your code is not runnable, so I couldn't test this, but you're using the same GridBagConstraints instance for all your components.  I see you setting c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL for your first component.  Is that what you want for all your components?  You're also setting the GridBagConstraints after you add them to the component.  Set them before the add.

Comment: Aha...that did it. I'd thought that you add the component before adding the component parameters, but it should be the other way around: define the parameters, then add the component. Also; code is updated so it's runnable.

Comment: At this point, yes, I want `HORIZONAL` for all my components. Once I get it working and I see how it looks, I'll be deciding to keep it or not...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to add a few lines to make your code really runnable.

You were setting the GridBagConstraints after you add them to the component. You must set them before the add.

The trick was to set the setHorizontalAlignment method of the JLabels that you wanted to center to a center alignment.

I formatted your code and added some Insets to make your GUI more visually appealing.

Here's a picture of the GUI.

[image: Button Test GUI]

And here's the code.

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ButtonSel extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JLabel  buttonSelLabel  = new JLabel("Choose Which Timer To Run");
    JButton pomoButton      = new JButton("00:25:00");
    JButton shrtButton      = new JButton("00:05:00");
    JButton longButton      = new JButton("00:30:00");
    JButton startButton     = new JButton("Go");
    JButton pauseButton     = new JButton("Pause");
    JButton quitButton      = new JButton("Quit");
    JLabel  textDisplay     = new JLabel("00:00:00");
    JPanel  timerPanel      = new JPanel();


    public ButtonSel() {
        super("ButtonTest");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        timerPanel = new JPanel();
        timerPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        c.weightx = 1.0D;
        c.weighty = 1.0D;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 0);
        c.ipadx = 0;
        c.ipady = 0;
        buttonSelLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        timerPanel.add(buttonSelLabel, c); // line 1

        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        timerPanel.add(pomoButton, c); // line 2

        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        timerPanel.add(shrtButton, c);

        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 10);
        timerPanel.add(longButton, c);

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 3;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 0);
        textDisplay.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        timerPanel.add(textDisplay, c); // line 3

        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 4;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 0);
        timerPanel.add(startButton, c); // line 4

        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 4;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        timerPanel.add(pauseButton, c);

        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 4;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
        timerPanel.add(quitButton, c);

        pomoButton.addActionListener(this);
        shrtButton.addActionListener(this);
        longButton.addActionListener(this);
        startButton.addActionListener(this);
        pauseButton.addActionListener(this);
        quitButton.addActionListener(this);

        this.add(timerPanel);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent radioSelect) {
        Object source = radioSelect.getSource();
        if (source == pomoButton)
            textDisplay.setText("00:25:00");
        else if (source == shrtButton)
            textDisplay.setText("00:05:00");
        else if (source == longButton)
            textDisplay.setText("00:30:00");
        else if (source == startButton)
            textDisplay.setText("Started");
        else if (source == pauseButton)
            textDisplay.setText("Paused");
        else if (source == quitButton)
            textDisplay.setText("Quit");
        else
            textDisplay.setText("00:00:00");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ButtonSel();            
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Awesome. Exactly what I was looking for. Two quick followup questions. Do the parameters set for displaying Line 1 carry through to all four lines, changing only if updated? For instance does  `c.weightx = 1.0D;` automatically carry through the rest of the panel? Or does adding an object reset everything back to defaults? Possibly related; what's the difference between `Constraints.CENTER;` and `(SwingConstants.CENTER);` and why are both needed?

Comment: 1) Yes, the GridBagConstraints parameters set for the only instance of GridBagConstraints carry through.  This is because you only have one instance.  I was taught that I needed a new GridBagConstraints for each component.  I don't believe that's true in 1.6 and 1.7.  2)  The Javadoc for setHorizontalAlignment used SwingConstants, so that's what I used.  :-)  3) The setHorizontalAlignment method sets the JLabel in the center of the defined area.  The GridBagConstraints.CENTER sets all of the text, buttons and labels, in the center (which is the default for JButtons).

Comment: (continued) You could probably remove the c.anchor assignment.  I tried different things until the GUI looked the way I wanted.

Comment: That makes a ton of sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think one solution is `BoxLayout()`. U can divide your panel at 4 independent panels.

1st - choose the time -  as one panel 
2nd - 5, 25,30 min
3rd - 00:00:00
4th - Start Pause Quit

then prepare Main panel  which add 4 panels  and use BoxLayout() / layout of this panel is important:
e.g.

```
JPanel p = new JPanel();
p.add(panel1);
p.add(panel2);
p.add(panel3);
p.add(panel4);
p.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

`BoxLayout.Y_AXIS`  - panel will be layouted from top to bottom